# Can I use Nielson Siegel to 'interpolate' par yield

Tags: fixed-income, bond, yield-curve, term-structure

The NS model initially set a parametric form for forwards and we can get equivalent zero rates. If I have a few par yields, can I simply fit the par yields to the NS form or the NS form of the zero rates?

Basically, I am assuming par yield is the form. I know I am deviating from initial NS model, but would this OK?